# What are the jobs of the two brothers in the movie "Suture"?

Tags: character, suture

What are the jobs of the two brothers in the movie [Suture](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108260/)? The story is about twins, and I don't remember their jobs. I think one is a doctor, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

According to a [synopsis of the book](http://www.timeout.com/london/film/suture), Vincent is a wealthy sophisticate (Trust fund baby), and Carl is a construction worker. However, they are not twins, as one is white and one is black. I believe they are half brothers.

Comment: Thx. In fact they seem to be twins. I remember that in the movie people don't see difference between them. I think the difference of skin is chosen to show the psychological difference between them.